# What is the difference between a meson and quarkonium?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, mesons

I read that quarkonium is a "flavourless" meson. However what does it mean for a meson to be flavourless? I thought composite particles don't have "flavour" in the first place, and flavour just means the species of an elementary particle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mesons consist of quark-antiquark pairs, so inherit their [flavor from those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavour_(particle_physics)#Quarks), additively.

From WP, you learn that

> The third component of isospin  $I_3$, 1/2  for the up quark and -1/2  for the down quark;
> Strangeness is S= -the number of  *s*  quarks + that of   strange antiquarks $\bar s$; Charm, C= number of c quarks - number of $\bar c$s;
> Bottomness  (or "beauty"),  B'=  - the number of *b*s + the number of $\bar b$s, etc...

In onia, where the quark and antiquark are of the same flavor (just as in, neutral, positronium the constituent charges are positive and negative) the net flavors cancel, and so  quarkonia are flavorless. So, e.g., the $\phi\sim s \bar s$ is strangeless, but the $K^+\sim u\bar s $ is strange; charmonium, $c\bar c$ is uncharmed, but the $D^+\sim c\bar d$ is charmed, etc...

Note the innocuous convention of the flavor pegged on the charge of the corresponding flavored quark, so it flip-flops with the charge! So the strange quark has negative S, the charmed quark has positive C, the bottom quark has negative B', etc...